# Visual Studio 2012 not loading DLL

Tags: visual-studio-2012, resharper

recently my system crashed and before that everything was working fine. But now Visual Studio is not loading DLL in reference. It shows yellow warning icon that DLL not found. I've found the following behaviour.

1. It is not adding any DLL.
2. Other project reference is properly being added.

Visual Studio is building the project properly and its working fine but due to this most of my code has been highlighted with red and my IntelliSense is not working.

I've tried the following

1. Discard my code and took the latest from SVN.
2. Cleared VS2012 Cache
3. Reinstall VS2012.
4. Repaired Microsoft.Net Framework.
5. Deleted reference and again added it.
6. I've created a test project and added a reference to it. It is working fine but not working in my Project.

None of the above-mentioned steps solved my issue, however same code is working fine on other's machine.

Thanks

Comment: Try checkout code from svn in different directory and create project from it

Comment: Tried it, not working.

Comment: It was Resharper that was causing the issue. Reinstalling it solved my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow my Resharper got corrupt. Reinstalling Resharper solved the problem.